# How to switch with git subtree to a different branch for one of the subtree projects

Tags: git, git-subtree

When I have a container project with bunch of `git subtree` directories, each tracking their respective `main`, how can I switch (and even create) a branch in one of the subtrees?

The setup being:

```
.\container-proj       # branch main
   .\sub-proj-1            # branch main
   .\sub-proj-2            # branch main
   .\sub-proj-3            # branch main
```

Now I want to ake changes and when I do

(.\container-proj) $ git checkout -b new-branch

I get

```
.\container-proj       # branch new-branch
   .\sub-proj-1            # branch main
   .\sub-proj-2            # branch main
   .\sub-proj-3            # branch main
```

Now I make changes

```
(.\container-proj) $ touch README.md
(.\container-proj) $ cd sub-proj-1
(.\container-proj\sub-proj-1) $ touch README.md
```

I can commit and push these changes with

```
(.\container-proj) $ git commit -m MyChange -a ; git push
```

but of course they ony get into my `container-proj`s branch `new-branch`.

I can publish the changes upstream into the `sub-proj-1` with

```
(.\container-proj) $ git subtree push --prefix sub-proj-1 sub-proj-1 main
```

but that will only push it into the `main` branch of the project.

I would like to have those changes in a branch `sub-new-branch` in that project.

Basically, that I have the setup

```
.\container-proj       # branch new-branch
   .\sub-proj-1            # branch sub-new-branch
   .\sub-proj-2            # branch main
   .\sub-proj-3            # branch main
```

for a while, but can easily switch back to `main` for `sub-proj-1`.